# Cropperjs set position

Tags: cropperjs

I'm trying to set default position to cropper. This is what I have:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const image = this.imageElement.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement;
    image.onload = () => {
      this.cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        checkCrossOrigin: true,
        checkOrientation: true,
        dragMode: 'none',
        zoomable: false,
        background: false,
        data: {
          width: 240,
          height: 130
        }
      });
    };
  }
```

I tried adding setCropBoxData like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const image = this.imageElement.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement;
    image.onload = () => {
      this.cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        checkCrossOrigin: true,
        checkOrientation: true,
        dragMode: 'none',
        zoomable: false,
        background: false,
        data: {
          width: 240,
          height: 130
        }
      });
      this.cropper.setCropBoxData({
         left: 100,
         right: 100
      })
    };
  }
```

But it's not working. I also tried using setData() method. Also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const image = this.imageElement.nativeElement as HTMLImageElement;
    image.onload = () => {
      this.cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        checkCrossOrigin: true,
        checkOrientation: true,
        dragMode: 'none',
        zoomable: false,
        background: false,
        data: {
          width: 240,
          height: 130,
          x: value,
          y: value
        }
      });
    };
  }
```

Added x,y properties in data object.